# Java Programming: Getter/Setter Questions

Tags: java, getter-setter

Ok had a few questions with Getter and Setter messages with java. I was wondering if my starting Variable is an Int, how would I turn it into a String? Also, if my String is only allowed to consist of numbers, how would I replace all of the non-numerical Characters from the string input? Example, initial variables is String name, and int age. Constructor wants both variable to be returned as String.

```
public class cat
 {
   String name;
   int age;
   public cat(String name, String age){
   this.name = name;
   }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see what conversions between `int` and `String` have to do with getters and setters particularly...

Comment: you have to explicitly change from int to String using `""+<var>`

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String str)` also comes to mind.

Comment: I assume you should read the basics of a introduction to java. The first chapters will solve all your problems.

Comment: Suggest going some java tutorials covering basic data types and conversions. Nice name, btw. Cookie, cookie COOKIE! (Nom nom nom)

Comment: @MeetTitan - that's going in the wrong direction.  You mean `Integer.toString(int)` or `String.valueOf(int)`

Comment: @StephenC, you're completely right. I am guilty of not reading the question as carefully as I should have. It should be `Integer.toString(int i)`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet actually its required to go from int to string. You start out with an int variable, and your constructor must return a string.

Comment: What constructor? There's a bunch of context you haven't specified, and the only *constructor* that would return a `String` is a `String` constructor - and you're not writing those. My point is that the question of "how do I convert an `int` to a `String`?" doesn't depend on where the `int` comes from or what you're doing with the `String`.

Comment: @MeetTitan: Yeah I used Integer.parseInt(String str) as well, but I just cant seem to get rid of all of the non-numerical characters.

Comment: @CookieMonst3r, getters and setters are the use of methods to change variables that may or may not be in scope or visible.

Comment: @Prashant: I would strongly recommend using `String.valueOf(var)` instead of using string concatenation when that's not actually the goal.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry for being broad, I will post the code above.

Comment: Call `yourString.toCharArray()` and loop over it checking `currentChar.isDigit()`. Then go read a java book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setter for integer variable as your instance variable **`age`** is integer:

```
public void setAge(String a)
{
  try
  {
    this.age = Integer.parseInt(a);
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //.. code
  }
}
```